# Access is denied error windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am getting error on following line

**StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;**

Exception is: 
ex  {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
at Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.get_PicturesLibrary()
at WinTooth.MainPage.d__0.MoveNext()} System.SystemException {System.UnauthorizedAccessException}

I have also added lines to register for a file association extension.
Please suggest/help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.pictureslibrary
says **Windows Phone 8:  This API is not intended to be used directly from your code.**

In my app I used

```
             var photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
             photoChooserTask.Completed += OnPhotoChooserTask_Completed;
             photoChooserTask.Show();
```

to pick a photo.

Comment: Ok but I think if its provided then there has to be way to use it. I have to iterate through all images of the phone. is any way to do it?

Comment: I didn't search through the whole list, but maybe you can find an example (sth. like an image library example) here:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/site/search?pageIndex=1

maybe (but didn't look at it):
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Photos-Sample-a38a2c8e

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem but my issue was that i was reading too much files using iBuffer so it was taking too much memory and it was causing out of memory issue. So i optimized it and this issue was fixed.