# New folder in visible phone memory windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to programmatically create a folder named "MyFolder" and a txt file in it in visible phone memory on windows phone 8. Please look carefully at the path: home>phone>pictures.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a possible [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379937/access-is-denied-error-windows-phone-8). Windows phone 8 (silverlight) doesn't supports creating visible files and folders.

Comment: But I saw that WhatsApp can create a folder inside pictures folder when i don't have a sd card. How it can do this?

Comment: To my knowledge,WhatsApp has developed app for Windows phone 8.1 and in windows phone 8.1 you have access to the knownfolders API.